# Creating an accessible ASP intranet page stored on SQL Server 2008 R2 on Corporate Network

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, webserver, intranet

I have an SQL Server 2008 R2 database for which I want to set up an internal dashboard type ASP based web-site for monitoring various KPIs.

I have developed reports in SSRS that I can link into these and am comfortable writing ASP code, but I am not really familiar with setting up the server to allow access for users to a web-page (or any idea how difficult this is).

This is running on our corporate network, so I am just hoping someone might be able to give me a couple of pointers on some basic steps or link to a tutorial which will enable me to set this up.

I am having some trouble finding information on this as any of my searches are relating to how to connect to databases via ASP or finding a company who will host an SQL Server on my behalf.

I can successfully open a basic ASP page on the server desktop that connects, etc, but I want other users within the company to be able to access a specific page on the server from which I can write custom pages.

I want the internal users to just be able to type ...

`http://servername/`

or some other alias and be taken straight to this page.

Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!

GMan

Comment: which version of IIS is the server running?

Comment: Hi Rhumborl - your question has led me onto a path of discovery!!  I have Googled along this line and found I needed to install the extra components and configure - thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

1) http--//--servername--
Add DNS entries on your local Domain Contorller (Local IT will do it), alternatively add host file entries to all of the systems/servers on your network as
Windows: http://www.accs-net.com/hosts/how_to_use_hosts.html
Linux/Unix: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/32394-adding-host-entry-another-machine.html

2) I can successfully open a basic ASP page on the server desktop that connects, etc, but I want other users within the company to be able to access a specific page on the server from which I can write custom pages.

By default, IIS will open up a locally running web page to everyone as anonymous unless it is blocked for a specific condition.

Let me know if you need further assistance. Thanks.